# How do I get the edit text value in text view from an alert box in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I want to get some integer value from the user he/she click on the an alert box will show and asks for enter the total budget. When he/she puts the total budget in the alert box field then it'll be show in text view in the same activity.

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried so far as part of the question, so that it would be easy for people to identify and correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Each dialog has a positive button, and that positive button has a callback where you can get the text from edit text, like `Edittext.getText` and display it for textview like `TextView.setText`.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // your work here
        textview.setText = Edittext.getText

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do refer to topic regarding custom dialog box:
[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

You can create a custom dialog box that have a custom layout
`R.layout.budget_dialog`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ffffffff">


  <EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit_budget"
    android:hint="Enter budget"
    android:layout_below="@+id/a"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_dialog"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_flat_red_selector"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then obtain the value by:

```
public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.budget_dialog);

    final EditText edtBudget = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_budget);
    Button dialogButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Get budget string value
            String budget = edtBudget.getText().toString();
            //Do something with your value
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
```